# Android Studio: Differentiating identical devices during testing

Tags: android, logging, android-studio

I'm testing an app, written in Android Studio, that has a client side and a server side. In an ideal world, I'd like to have them both set up for USB debugging, each with their own log window.

But here's a hurdle I'm hitting before even getting that far: Android Studio only sees one device. Both devices show up as "BLU BLU DASH 3.5 Android 4.2.2 (API 17)" with a serial number of 1234567890ABCDEF. In the upload window, I only see a single device. It figures. How would AndroidStudio tell them apart, when even their serial numbers are the same?
[image]
How would you distinguish these devices so I can label one as the client, and one as the server, and pick which one I'm uploading the code to?

Comment: Already doing that. I've got both projects open at the same time, with each project getting its own virtual screen (under OSX).

Comment: So you have two pieces of hardware connected to the computer and they show up as one device?

Comment: nasch - That's right. I have two android phones of the same make, model, and software update. Only one device shows up in Android Studio, leading me to believe that the editor can't distinguish between the devices.